# Comando que Verifique se um software está instalado no Ubuntu

Tags: shell-script

Script que Verifique se um software está instalado no Ubuntu.
Se tiver instalado continua com a sequencia de comandos. se não pergunta se o usuário deseja instalar assim mesmo

Exemplo:

```
if (programa1=Instalado, programa2=instalado); then  
continua script;  
else  
echo "Voce precisa do programa1 e ele não está instalado, deseja continuar  
 assim mesmo?"  
"sim"  
continua script  
"não"  
Sai do script
```

Eu sei que por DEB dá pra fazer isso, usado o control mas gostaria de usar um script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o comando [`command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) informando o argumento `-v`

```
echo $(command -v git)
```

no exemplo acima, se *git* foi encontrado terá um retorno semelhante ao abaixo:

```
>> /usr/bin/git
```

caso contrário, irá retornar nada.

```
>>
```

Verificando o retorno:

```
if ! [ -x "$(command -v git)" ]; then
    echo 'git não instalado.' >&2
    exit 1
else
    echo 'git instalado.'
fi
```

Veja [funcionando em tutorialspoint.com](http://tpcg.io/tozyKA)

> Vale lembrar que funciona em todos os sistemas que utilizam o [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) como interpretador de comandos.

#### Referência

- [Bash Builtin Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins)